# Get shipping class cost using shipping class id in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I need the shipping class cost of products.

```
 $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
 $items = $order->get_items();
 foreach ($items as $item) {
     $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
     $shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id();
 }
```

How can I fetch shipping class cost based on shipping class id?

Answer (score 0):

`WooCommerce`: Shipping classes are independent from Shipping Zones and Methods. Shipping class cost depends on the customer location and on the selected shipping method.

So the answer is **its not possible**